# Android: how to get a Canvas' current clip path?

Tags: android, canvas

I have a situation where I am drawing to Canvas.  As I draw, I sometimes need to update the Canvas' clip by intersecting the clip with a given path.  This works great.  But, I have the situation where I need to create a new Canvas for new series of drawing commands, but it needs to start with the previous Canvas' clip.  Because Path does not expose an intersect() method, and because Canvas does not expose a getCurrentClipPath() method, the only solution I can think of is to keep a list of previously used paths, and apply them sequentially to my new canvas.  However, this solution has memory and cpu ramifications.

Am I missing an obvious way to retrieve a Canvas' current clip path, or to create a new Canvas using properties (but not drawing commands) from an old one?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Canvas.save() prior to installing your new clip region and then Canvas.restore() when you want to return to the old one.

- [Android javadoc: Canvas.save()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#save%28int%29)

Comment: Actually, what I'm trying to do is to initialize a new Canvas using the clipPath from an old Canvas.